# android listview long press select part of text

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

I have a ListView where each item is a TextView.
I want to enable the long press behaviour to select part of text and then be able to "Select all", "Copy" using "Text Selection" Context Action Bar. I researched and tried various solutions. None of them worked for my situation.

I also have a single select popup menu to process.

Could anyone please have a solution?

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity4 extends Activity
{

  List<String> stringList;
  ListView listView;
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
      stringList.add("verse --" + i + " -- The Lord is my shepherd. I shall not want.");
    }
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_vew, stringList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
      {
        view.setSelected(true);
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity4.this, view);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
          {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity4.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
          }
        }); 
        popup.show();
      }
    });

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   //able to select part of list text. Example "shepherd".
  // Then show Context Action Bar (CAB) that highlights selected text (example "shepherd") shows "Select All" "Copy" on the CAB
  }

}
```

acticity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rl"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

popup_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:title="bookmark"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/copyVerseToClipboard"
    android:title="copy verse to clipboard"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="share"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:title="cancel"/>

</menu>
```

text_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:minHeight="15dp"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingRight="10dp"
          android:textSize="20sp"

  >
</TextView>
```